# list of IPs that are source of brute force attacks

Tags: hacking, brute-force-attacks

I'm getting a lot of attempts to bruteforce into a database. Possibly other attempts too, but this is what I'm focusing on for now.

I've compiled a list of IP addresses that are sources of this attack. I'd like to compare them to the list and implement the list for banning of the ips on the firewall

where can I find a list of IPs that have been reported to be source of brute force attacks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking -- "Where can I get a list of all hosts that have ever launched a brute force attack on the internet?"

Comment: A simple Google search would turn up many such lists; and even [lists-of-lists](http://www.selectrealsecurity.com/public-block-lists).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a list but check out [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/), if you're using Linux, it may be much easier for you to just implement this.

Comment: I've come across that on a similar question, but I'm working with a windows host, so that wouldn't work for me